# can't to use 2 option menus - android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to use 2 items. The "delete" item works OK. Even though they both appear correctly in the screen, the share button, doesn't react to touches. What's wrong here ?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="Delete all records"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"/>
</menu>
```

and here is the activity class :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.next_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete:
        // code here
        break;
    case R.id.menu_item_share:
         ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        String shareSubject = "test Subject";
        String shareText = "test 123";
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSubject);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
        myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I used the share action in one of my projects.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionProvider(shareItem);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, curTaskTv
                .getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, curTaskTv.getText()
                .toString());
        return intent;
    }
```

It seems you have to do the Intent stuff in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method

Comment: i know how to use share action alone and menu option too, but it's not working when used simultaneously